# What is the equivalent of the C# 'var' keyword in Java?

Tags: java, keyword, var

One use of the *var* keyword in C# is implicit type declaration. What is the Java equivalent syntax for *var*?

Comment: `val` (or `var`) if you use a particular "Java replacement" language ;-)

Comment: @pst: that would be Scala? Hm yes, it is.

Comment: For IntelliJ, I submitted this as a feature request: http://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-102808  The IDE could collapse code to show val or var even though the underlying code wouldn't have it.

Comment: @Jon I've hacked something together for IntelliJ, see my [answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/16002535/115866).

Comment: There's still no var keyword / type inference in Java 8, correct? http://leftoblique.net/wp/2013/07/25/java-8-a-k-a-oracle-finally-catches-up-to-net-framework-3-0

Comment: There is now a proposal for this feature to be included in Java - http://openjdk.java.net/jeps/286

Comment: Perhaps you can try Kotlin https://kotlinlang.org/
Great talk about Kotlin. https://youtu.be/R0J_Jl7bKY8

Comment: @McGin [It's now alive](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3443858/what-is-the-equivalent-of-the-c-sharp-var-keyword-in-java/48933006#48933006).

Answer (score 269, accepted):

There is none. Alas, you have to type out the full type name.

Edit: 7 years after being posted, type inference for local variables (with `var`) was added in Java 10.

Edit: 6 years after being posted, to collect some of the comments from below:

- The reason C# has the `var` keyword is because it's possible to have Types that have no name in .NET. Eg:

  ```
  var myData = new { a = 1, b = "2" };
  ```

  In this case, it would be impossible to give a proper type to `myData`. 6 years ago, this was impossible in Java (all Types had names, even if they were extremely verbose and unweildy). I do not know if this has changed in the mean time.
- `var` is not the same as `dynamic`. `var`iables are still 100% statically typed. This will not compile:

  ```
  var myString = "foo";
  myString = 3;
  ```
- `var` is also useful when the type is obvious from context. For example:

  ```
  var currentUser = User.GetCurrent();
  ```

  I can say that in any code that I am responsible for, `currentUser` has a `User` or derived class in it. Obviously, if your implementation of `User.GetCurrent` return an int, then maybe this is a detriment to you.
- This has nothing to do with `var`, but if you have weird inheritance hierarchies where you shadow methods with other methods (eg `new public void DoAThing()`), don't forget that non-virtual methods are affected by the Type they are cast as.

  I can't imagine a real world scenario where this is indicative of good design, but this may not work as you expect:

  ```
  class Foo {
      public void Non() {}
      public virtual void Virt() {}
  }

  class Bar : Foo {
      public new void Non() {}
      public override void Virt() {}
  }

  class Baz {
      public static Foo GetFoo() {
          return new Bar();
      }
  }

  var foo = Baz.GetFoo();
  foo.Non();  // <- Foo.Non, not Bar.Non
  foo.Virt(); // <- Bar.Virt

  var bar = (Bar)foo;
  bar.Non();  // <- Bar.Non, not Foo.Non
  bar.Virt(); // <- Still Bar.Virt
  ```

  As indicated, virtual methods are not affected by this.
- No, there is no non-clumsy way to initialize a `var` without an actual variable.

  ```
  var foo1 = "bar";        //good
  var foo2;                //bad, what type?
  var foo3 = null;         //bad, null doesn't have a type
  var foo4 = default(var); //what?
  var foo5 = (object)null; //legal, but go home, you're drunk
  ```

  In this case, just do it the old fashioned way:

  ```
  object foo6;
  ```

Comment: And to be fair also; 1. it's only recent in C#, so Arturo can't be blaming "creators" and 2. it's only due to some other features that weren't in the 1.0 of either language that its become an idea that is useful rather than a great way to make code less clear and more bug-prone. It's needed in C#3.0, and would have a few useful cases in C#2.0, but would have been a bad thing in C#1.0.

Comment: @Mike Caron: and because of certain very long types (without `var`, that would make Linq practically unusable).

Comment: @pst What does implicit typing have to do with polymorphism? The `var` keyword is 100% identical to declaring a variable with the exact type of the expression. That's all.

Comment: @Mike Caron: C# has [default] non-virtual calls and operators are not virtual so... `var p = new X(); p.Z()` is not the same as `SuperX p = new X(); p.Z()` for all X and and SuperX, even though `X : SuperX`. With `var` the *static* type of `p` is always `X` in first example above, but always `SuperX` in the second example. A subtle but important difference to be aware of. But your answer is very correct :-)

Comment: @Jon Hanna: `var` does not make the code less clear. Rather the opposite in my opinion. Why for example write the type two (or even three) times on the same row when you declare and instantiate it (`RadioButton radioButton = new RadioButton();`)? `var` makes you rather think twice when you are naming your variables because it turns the focus on the functionality rather than the type (for example  `UserCollection collection = new userRepository.GetUsers();` rather more naturally turns into `var users = userRepository.GetUsers();`). If you think `var` is unclear it is just because unused to it.

Comment: @MartinOdhelius `var` very definitely can make code clear used well, but it can also make it unclear too used badly; like many formatting options. The balance differs depending on how much you use anonymous objects and generics, neither of which existed in .NET 1.0, making it less useful as a hypothetical keyword in the first version of C♯.
I would only name a `RadioButton` `radioButton` in the case of a factory or helper method where the only thing significant about the button was that it was a `RadioButton`, otherwise that's madness with or without `var`.

Comment: @Jon Hanna: I was once as critical to `var` as you, if not more, but I have changed my opinion, and perhaps it is as simple as an question of different opinions, because I still think you are wrong when you say it is a matter how much you are using anonymous objects and generics ;) The type declaration is most often just code noise, if you can not understand the code without it the code is probably unclear in either case.

Comment: @MartinOdhelius Who said I was critical of var? One of my favourite things about SharpDevelop2.0 was that it had a feature that would turn typing e.g. `? x = a.CompareTo(b);` into `int x = a.CompareTo(b);` and so on, which is the closest we could have to `var` without language support. So I was using `var` before there was `var`.

Comment: I'm sorry, but "var currentUser = User.GetCurrent();" is not inherently obvious what you're getting back.  You may likely get an instance of the User class, but you could also easily be getting the user's name as a string or a user ID as an integer, or any combination of things.  You correctly point this out in your text, but this particular example actually demonstrates how var can grossly obfuscate a situation rather than clarify it.

Comment: You're confusing [var](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/var) with [anonymous types](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/classes-and-structs/anonymous-types). `var` itself simply asks the compiler to infer the type from the assignment; it's syntactic sugar. I was skeptical of it at first, but I use it religiously and have yet to encounter a time where it caused confusion. It removes redundancy when instantiating and removes the need to check the type when referencing. There is no JAVA equivalent as of JAVA 9.

Comment: Java 10 is expected to have type inference, see https://blog.codefx.org/java/java-10-var-type-inference/

Comment: @Robear The only place where it may (but doesn't have to) cause confusion is where you can't use your IDE to point out proper type. For instance, take code review boards.

Comment: Heavy use of var is great because then when something isn't typed as a var it's a hint that something interesting is about to happen related to typing.  It functions as a "pay attention to this next bit" when used well.

Answer (score 46):

If you add Lombok to your project you can use its **val** keyword.

http://projectlombok.org/features/val.html

Comment: @rightfold: Objects whose reference is `final` are not necessarily immutable. Consider `final StringBuilder strB = new StringBuilder("My reference is final"); strB.append("I'm not immutable");`

Comment: Since lombok v1.16.12 there is also experimental support for `var`. https://projectlombok.org/features/experimental/var.html

Comment: @MatthiasBraun your example is wrong. In this case StringBuilder class itself is immutable, you just adding string value to its internal structure using method, this is totally legal.

Answer (score 28):

JEP - JDK Enhancement-Proposal

http://openjdk.java.net/jeps/286

JEP 286: Local-Variable Type Inference

Author  Brian Goetz

```
// Goals:
var list = new ArrayList<String>();  // infers ArrayList<String>
var stream = list.stream();          // infers Stream<String>
```

Comment: What version of Java? 10?

Comment: @PeterMortensen Yes. JEP 286 has been accepted and published in JDK 10 (see 286 under Features at http://openjdk.java.net/projects/jdk/10/).

Answer (score 23):

With the release of JDK 10 on March 20, Java now includes a `var` reserved type name (not a keyword—see below) as specified in [JEP 286](http://openjdk.java.net/jeps/286). For local variables, the following is now valid in Java 10 or higher:

```
var map = new HashMap<String, Integer>();
```

The `var` reserved type name in Java is nearly identical to the `var` keyword in C# in that both allow for implicit typing (see below for important differences). `var` in Java can only be used for implicit type inference in the following contexts (as enumerated in [JEP 286: Goals](http://openjdk.java.net/jeps/286#Goals)):

- local variables with initializers
- indexes in the enhanced for-loop
- locals declared in a traditional for-loop

Therefore `var` *cannot* be used for fields, return types, class names, or interface names. Its rationale is to remove the need for including long type names when declaring and defining local variables, as stated in [JEP 286](http://openjdk.java.net/jeps/286)  (authored by Brian Goetz):

> We seek to improve the developer experience by reducing the ceremony
>   associated with writing Java code, while maintaining Java's commitment
>   to static type safety, by allowing developers to elide the
>   often-unnecessary manifest declaration of local variable types.

### `var` Scoping in Java

It should be noted that `var` is not a keyword in Java, but rather a reserved type name. As quoted from JEP 286:

> The identifier var is not a keyword; instead it is a reserved type
>   name. This means that code that uses var as a variable, method, or
>   package name will not be affected; code that uses var as a class or
>   interface name will be affected (but these names are rare in practice,
>   since they violate usual naming conventions).

Note that since `var` is a reserved type name and not a keyword, it can still be used for package names, method names, and variable names (along with its new type-interference role). For example, the following are all examples of valid uses of `var` in Java:

```
var i = 0;
var var = 1;
for (var i = 0; i < 10; i++) { /* ... */ }
public int var() { return 0; }
package var;
```

As quoted from JEP 286:

> This treatment would be restricted to local variables with
>   initializers, indexes in the enhanced for-loop, and locals declared in
>   a traditional for-loop; it would not be available for method formals,
>   constructor formals, method return types, fields, catch formals, or
>   any other kind of variable declaration.

### Differences Between `var` in Java & C

This is one notable difference between `var` in C# and Java include the following: `var` can be used as a type name in C# but cannot be used as a class name or interface name in Java. According to the [C# documentation (Implicitly Typed Local Variables)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/classes-and-structs/implicitly-typed-local-variables):

> If a type named `var` is in scope, then the `var` keyword will resolve to
>   that type name and will not be treated as part of an implicitly typed
>   local variable declaration.

The ability to use `var` as a type name in C# creates some complexity and introduces some intricate resolution rules, which are avoided by `var` in Java by disallowing `var` as a class or interface name. For information on the complexities of `var` type names in C#, see [Restrictions apply to implicitly-typed variable declarations](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18481712/2403253). For more information on the rationale behind the scoping decision for `var in Java, see [JEP 286: Scoping Choices](http://openjdk.java.net/jeps/286#Scope-Choices).

Comment: Is there any difference between Java and c# in that you can't use `var` for fields or return types? Why is it important to note?

Comment: @user1306322 In that context, no. `var` in Java cannot be used for fields or return types. This is important because this restriction makes `var` context-sensitive, where it can only be used in some contexts (local variables) and not others. This is not necessarily a difference between Java and C# that should be noted, but an important restriction in general when using `var` in Java.

Comment: I just looked up and it seems like in c# you can make `var` a class name and use it as such. Technically it is a "context keyword" in case of c#, but in Java it seems that you can't do the same. Correct me if I'm wrong.

Comment: You are correct. You cannot use `var` as a class name or an interface name in Java (which is not common anyway), but you can use it for variable names, method names, and package names. For example, `var var = 1;` is a valid Java statement but trying to declare a class as `public class var {}` results in an error: `as of release 10, 'var' is a restricted local variable type and cannot be used for type declarations`. I've updated the answer above to go into more detail on the rationale behind `var` in Java and its differences with `var` in C#.

Answer (score 20):

I have cooked up a plugin for IntelliJ that – in a way – gives you `var` in Java. It's a hack, so the usual disclaimers apply, but if you use IntelliJ for your Java development and want to try it out, it's at https://bitbucket.org/balpha/varsity.

Comment: It'd be great to have a keyboard shortcut to fold/unfold declaration types in the current editor. Great plugin though.

Comment: @hotkey This uses IntelliJ's built-in code folding, so you can unfold everything with Ctrl-Shift-NumPadPlus. When the cursor is on a line that contains a folded variable declaration, you can Ctrl-NumPadPlus and Ctrl-NumPadMinus to fold/unfold the declarations in the current method. Folding all declarations is a bit awkward, you have fold everything (Ctrl-Shift-NumPadMinus) and then unfold everything again (Ctrl-Shift-NumPadPlus).

Answer (score 11):

It will be supported in JDK 10. It's even possible to see it in action in the [early access build](http://jdk.java.net/10/).

The [JEP 286](http://openjdk.java.net/jeps/286):

> Enhance the Java Language to extend type inference to declarations of local variables with initializers.

So now instead of writing:

```
List<> list = new ArrayList<String>();
Stream<> stream = myStream();
```

You write:

```
var list = new ArrayList<String>();
var stream = myStream();
```

Notes:

- `var` is now a [reserved type name](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49089124/what-type-of-token-exactly-is-var-in-java-10)
- Java is **still** commitment to static typing!
- It can be only used in *local* variable declarations

---

If you want to give it a try without installing Java on your local system, I created a [Docker image](https://hub.docker.com/r/marounbassam/ubuntu-java10/) with JDK 10 installed on it:

```
$ docker run -it marounbassam/ubuntu-java10 bash
root@299d86f1c39a:/# jdk-10/bin/jshell
Mar 30, 2018 9:07:07 PM java.util.prefs.FileSystemPreferences$1 run
INFO: Created user preferences directory.
|  Welcome to JShell -- Version 10
|  For an introduction type: /help intro

jshell> var list = new ArrayList<String>();
list ==> []
```

Comment: Beware, the code you provided (before/after `var`) is not equivalent. In the `var` example `list` is of type `ArrayList`, not a `List`.

Answer (score 8):

A simple solution (assuming you're using a decent IDE) is to just type 'int' everywhere and then get it to set the type for you.

I actually just added a class called 'var' so I don't have to type something different.

The code is still too verbose, but at least you don't have to type it!

Comment: When you say "decent IDE" is Eclipse* excluded? -- this does not appear to work in Luna (at least when I just tried it with `int`) -- am I missing something? (*: while I would never call Eclipse a decent IDE, I can't judge for others...)

Comment: @BrainSlugs83 dunno I'm using IDEA, not really used eclipse before.  Doesn't it correct types for you?  I'm used to c#/visual studio/resharper which is like IDEA except it actually works properly!  In all the jetbrains' ones you can press alt-enter to get a list of suggestions when there's an error - so setting type to int introduces an error you can alt-enter on and get it to sort the type out

Answer (score 6):

As of Java 10, the equivalent is ... `var`.

Comment: Are there *any* differences? I mean you know better than to write short answers like this, what with your rep level n all. And surely there must be *some* differences.

Comment: @user1306322 That's a wholly separate question!  You might check the java-10 tag, as many aspects of this have already been asked.

Comment: Well, this is *the* question to look at if you're googling this, as it comes first and is linked to in every related post in the sidebar. So I suppose if you know that separate question which answers it, you might be able to at least link to it or include parts of it into your answer.

Answer (score 5):

You can take a look to [Kotlin](http://kotlinlang.org/) by JetBrains, but it's val. not var.

Comment: Kotlin has val and var. val is equivelent to declaring a variable final in java, var allows reassignment.

Answer (score 5):

Java 10 did get local variable type inference, so now it has `var` which is pretty much equivalent to the C# one (so far as I am aware).

It can also infer non-denotable types (types which couldn't be named in that place by the programmer; though *which* types are non-denotable is different). See e.g. [Tricks with `var` and anonymous classes (that you should never use at work)](https://blog.codefx.org/java/tricks-var-anonymous-classes/).

The one difference I could find is that in C#,

> [If a type named var is in scope, then the var keyword will resolve to that type name and will not be treated as part of an implicitly typed local variable declaration.](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/classes-and-structs/implicitly-typed-local-variables#remarks)

In Java 10 `var` is not a legal type name.

Answer (score 3):

I know this is older but why not create a var class and create constructors with different types and depending on what constructors gets invoked you get var with different type. You could even build in methods to convert one type to another.

Answer (score 3):

[`Lombok` supports var](https://projectlombok.org/features/experimental/var) but it's still classified as experimental:

```
import lombok.experimental.var;

var number = 1; // Inferred type: int
number = 2; // Legal reassign since var is not final
number = "Hi"; // Compilation error since a string cannot be assigned to an int variable
System.out.println(number);
```

[Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47122653) is a pitfall to avoid when trying to use it in `IntelliJ IDEA`. It appears to work as expected though including auto completion and everything. Until there is a "non-hacky" solution (e.g. due to [JEP 286: Local-Variable Type Inference](http://openjdk.java.net/jeps/286)), this might be your best bet right now.

Note that `val` is support by `Lombok` as well without modifying or creating a `lombok.config`.

Answer (score 2):

You can, in Java 10, but only for **Local** variables, meaning,

You can,

`var anum = 10; var aString = "Var";`

But can't,

`var anull = null; // Since the type can't be inferred in this case`

Check out the [spec](https://developer.oracle.com/java/jdk-10-local-variable-type-inference) for more info.

Comment: This is incorrect.  `var` can be used for many forms of non-denotable types, including capture types, intersection types, and anonymous class types.  And, as of Java 11, it can also be applied to lambda parameters.

Answer (score 0):

In general you can use Object class for any type, but you have do type casting later!

eg:-

```
Object object = 12;
    Object object1 = "Aditya";
    Object object2 = 12.12;

    System.out.println(Integer.parseInt(object.toString()) + 2);

    System.out.println(object1.toString() + " Kumar");
    System.out.println(Double.parseDouble(object2.toString()) + 2.12);
```

Comment: Aditya, please check all your other answers. Many of them have -1 and probably for a good reason. Don't just post whatever if you're not sure it's correct.

Comment: @user1306322 
what's the problem in my answer! 
can u elaborate? 
can't we use Object class for all data type?

Comment: Object object = 12;
  Object object1 = "Aditya";
  Object object2 = 12.12;

  System.out.println(Integer.parseInt(object.toString()) + 2);

  System.out.println(object1.toString() + " Kumar");
  System.out.println(Double.parseDouble(object2.toString()) + 2.12);

Comment: The problem is you didn't understand the question. The question was not "how to make this work", but "is there a thing like this". You answer the wrong question. With the `var` word now officially in the language, your answer is also referring to the now old fashioned way.

Answer (score -1):

This feature is now available in Java SE 10. The static, type-safe var has finally made it into the java world :)

source: https://www.oracle.com/corporate/pressrelease/Java-10-032018.html