# Restrictions apply to implicitly-typed variable declarations

Tags: c#, .net

I was reading about Implicitly Typed Local Variables (var) on

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb384061.aspx

It states one restriction :

> If a type named var is in scope, then the var keyword will resolve to that type name and will not be treated as part of an implicitly typed local variable declaration.

Can anybody explain what is mean by statement with C# example?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

That if you do this:

```
class var
{
    public static implicit operator var(int value)
    {
        return new var();
    }
}

var myVar = 5;
```

The `myVar` will be of type `var` and not of type `int`.

(the `operator` I've added is so that there is an implicit conversion from `int` to `var`).

This rule was inserted because `var` wasn't a reserved keyword in C# (and still isn't... If you look [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/x53a06bb.aspx) you'll see it's a "contextual keyword"), so a class/struct/enum named `var` was valid in C# 2.0 .

- *If a type named var is in scope*: if there is a class/struct/enum named var that is in scope (so "reachable" by simply writing var, without having to use a namespace)
- *then the var keyword will resolve to that type name*: then `var` means "your user defined type" and not "the keyword var"