# Can there be 'var' keyword in Java?

Tags: java, android

My question can seem stupid... to me it really seems stupid. 
But I was shocked to see `var` keyword in a java code in video tutorial about android, [you can see it here, on 38 minute for example...](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=_q9lorDZn0Y)

So my question is, how it is possible to have `var` in java code and what does it mean in java, where we cannot have references without specific type?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The tutorial you're seeing is using Xamarin, which means they're writing the Android apps using C#, not Java.

There's no `var` keyword in Java before Java 10.

From Java 10 and on, you can use `var` to define local variables in methods and specific scopes.

Some examples:

```
var list = new ArrayList<String>();
list.add("Hello world");

Consumer<String> reader = s -> {
    var data = s.split("\\s+"); //data is of type String[]
    //use data...
    //...
}
```

You cannot do the following:

- To define attributes of a class. Example

  ```
  class MyClass {
      private var foo = 5; //compile error
  }
  ```
- As arguments in methods. Example

  ```
  public void method(var foo) { } //compile error
  ```

Answer (score 6):

Actually, now that JDK 10 had been released on 2018/03/20 java supports the use of the var keyword to perform Local variable type inference.

This means that instead of doing this:
`String myName = "steeltoe";`

You can just do `var myName = "steeltoe";`

Java will then infer that it is a string and as such is equivalent to the previous version just with less typing.

It should be noted that this does not break static typing as java still makes `myName` a `String` and as such will not allow you to break static typing by assigning it to a integer, like this `myName = 1234;`

Comment: But Android doesn't support Java 10 features.

Answer (score 0):

// similar post:

[C# var keyword equivalent in java?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3443858/c-sharp-var-keyword-equivalent-in-java)

---

JEP - JDK Enhancement-Proposal

http://openjdk.java.net/jeps/286

JEP 286: Local-Variable Type Inference

Author Brian Goetz

```
// Goals:
var list = new ArrayList<String>();  // infers ArrayList<String>
var stream = list.stream();          // infers Stream<String>
```