# Lombok IntelliJ IDEA Plugin: Use of var is disabled by default

Tags: java, intellij-idea, lombok, intellij-lombok-plugin

I'm using the [`Lombok Plugin`](https://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/6317-lombok-plugin) for [`IntelliJ IDEA`](https://www.jetbrains.com/idea/). When try to run `Java` code using the `var` keyword, I get the following error:

`Use of var is disabled by default. Please add 'lombok.var.flagUsage = ALLOW' to 'lombok.config' if you want to enable is.`

How do you do that in `IntelliJ IDEA`? I created the `lombok.config` in the project root and pasted `lombok.var.flagUsage = ALLOW` but it didn't fix it. `val` is working but not `var`. I can't seem to find clear instructions on enabling `var`.

My [`Lombok` maven dependency](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.projectlombok/lombok/1.16.18) is:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
    <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
    <version>1.16.18</version>
    <scope>provided</scope>
</dependency>
```

Comment: You may need to recompile everything in order to observe the effect.

Comment: @maaartinus: Yeah, that was it. Thank you. Pretty stupid I forgot about that.

Comment: Live and programming would be too simple if we never forget such stupid things. Please either delete your question or I'll convert my comment into an answer. It may be useful for someone or not (given the huge number of questions). I don't care.

Comment: I believe it could be useful eventually so please post an answer and that's going to be it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may need to recompile everything in order to observe the effect.

Actually, any change of any `lombok.config` anywhere should trigger a recompilation of all classes in the subtree. This is not the case as such changes are rare and don't warrant the probably non-trivial amount of work.