# Variable named “var” causing compilation error

Tags: java, variables

while using `JFrame`, I tried setting the icon image with the following code

```
ImageIcon image = new ImageIcon("C:\\barney.jpg");
frame.setIconImage(image.getImage());
```

It works as expected, but when I set the `"C:\\barney.jpg"` as a`String` variable

```
String var = "C:\\barney.jpg";
ImageIcon image = new ImageIcon(var);
frame.setIconImage(image.getImage());
```

The compiler displays `Exception in thread "main" java.lang.Error: Unresolved compilation problem`

Another point of confusion is why the line in the `error` code refer to the
`public static void main(String[] args)` line instead of
`String var = "C:\\barney.jpg";` which actually causes the error?

Comment: Depending on the java version `var` is a really bad variable name. Actually regardless of the java version it is a bad name since the variable name should hint at the meaning / usage of it.

Comment: Did you try not naming it var? Isn't var a keyword in Java nowadays?

Comment: @ Thomas Stachl, i just changed the variable to `x` and i still experience the same thing

Comment: The error message will contain more than that _Unresolved compilation problem_. Include that in your question. Also, don't try to run code that doesn't compile.

Comment: @sotirios I swear, that's the only error I'm getting. I use VS code, could that be why?

Comment: Try to compile with `javac` directly. Please provide a [mcve].

Answer (score 2):

`var` is a reserved keyword in java. You can't name any variable `var`. Try some other name.

The reason behind this is that `var` is used for assigning variables so to not confuse the compiler you cannot use it as a variable name.

Note that it does compile in java 8 and prior as the `var` keyword has not had been implemented back then. Additionally starting from java 17 it is possible again to use it as a variable name.

`var`, with some limitations lets you replace standart assignments in java.

```
String someString1 = "Hello, World!";
// gets turned into
var someString2 = "Hello, World!";
```

This also works with other assignments

Comment: Ah Interesting. Didn't know it was possible in java 17!

Comment: @jadefalke changing the variable name still causes the same exception, i used `x` instead of `var`

Comment: @user16320675 `Exception in thread "main" java.lang.Error: Unresolved compilation problem: at a1.main(a1.java:5)` that's all i'm getting

Comment: @ser.T please don't edit a question in such a way that the original question is not inferable anymore

Comment: That is not correct. **var** is __not__ a reserved keyword, rather it is a reserved type name in Java, and so you can use variable with **var** name. See here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49102553/what-is-the-conceptual-difference-between-a-restricted-keyword-and-reserved-t#:~:text=A%20%22reserved%20type%20name%22%20is,using%20an%20additional%20lookup%20step.

Comment: P.S: See the JLS section about keywords: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-3.html#jls-3.9