# How is var different than other keywords?

Tags: c#, c#-3.0

I just found out that you can use `var` as fieldname.

```
var var = "";
```

Why is this possible? Any other keyword as fieldname would not compile.

```
var string = ""; // error
```

Comment: [This](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/ericlippert/2009/05/11/reserved-and-contextual-keywords/) has some insight on the topic

Comment: [var](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/var) appears from C# 3.0, if it would become reserved keyword, then this change would break a lot of code.

Comment: Just because I think it fits somehow, here is [basically the same question for Java](https://stackoverflow.com/q/49089124/3182664)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Well, `string` is a *keyword*

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/

we *can't use* it as an identifier:

```
// doesn't compile
var string = "";
// doesn't compile as well
int string = 123;
```

However, we can put `String` (capitalized) identifier

```
var String = ""; 
string String = "";
String String = "";
```

On the contrary `var` is *not* a keyword, it's a *contextual keyword* only (i.e. it's a keyword in *some contexts* only); that's why the lines below are correct ones:

```
string var = "";
int var = 123;
var var = "";
```

Answer (score 1):

In addition to other answers, `string` is a keyword of the language and you can not declare a variable with this name. This is also applied to other keywords like `int`, `double`, `char`, `event` etc. You can use the `@` to escape this name. For sample:

```
var @string = "This is a string";
var @var = "This is a string declared named var";
var @int = 123;
var @double = 10.42;
```

And everytime you need to use it, you have to use the `@`. For sample:

```
Console.WriteLine(@string);
```

It is not a good pratice, avoid this kind of name to variables, objects, arguments, methods, etc.

Comment: You are probably missing "in addition to other answer" at the beginning of answer. I was confused to read about `@` when question is about allowed `var var`.