# Referencing fields of an Inner Class

Tags: java, anonymous-class

I'm new to java and trying to understand how anonymous inner classes work.

```
Object a = new Object(){
    Object b = new Object(){
        String c = "Hi!";
    };
};

System.out.println( a.b.c );
```

When I try to run the code above, I get a 'cannot find symbol' error. Can somebody explain me why am I getting this error and how can I reference the String c.

(*The reason why I am trying 'a possibly weird' thing is I wanted to organize widget handles in a hierarchical way like 'ui.menu.file.open'.*)

Comment: The type of `a` is `Object`, and `b` is not part of its interface. You need a non-anonymous class for this.

Comment: If you want hierarchical constants, try nested classes, e.g., `class Ui { class Menu { class File { static final String OPEN = "foo"; }}}`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

While the *dynamic* type of variable `a` is an anonymous type that has field `c`, its *static* type is `Object`, which does not have field `c`.

You would be able to solve this problem once Java introduces `var` declarations, which derive the type implicitly. Unfortunately, [this wouldn't be available until Java 10](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49598148/335858):

```
// ** WARNING ** This would not compile until Java 10
var a = new Object() {
    String c = "Hi!";
};
System.out.println( a.c );
```

Until then you would have to declare a common type for your anonymous objects, and have it expose the properties that you need:

```
interface HasMyProperty {
    String getC();
}
interface HasMyObject {
    HasMyProperty getB();
}
...
HasMyObject a = new HasMyObject() {
    HasMyProperty b = new HasMyProperty() {
        private final String c = "Hi!";
        @Override
        public string getC() { return c; }
    };
    @Override
    public HasMyProperty getB() { return b; }
};
System.out.println( a.getB().getC() );
```

Comment: @cppbeginner Right, I didn't see the second level there. I removed it now, and added a more down-to-earth example for the current versions of Java.

Answer (score 0):

Here `b` and `c` are fields of the anonymous classes but you cannot refer to them outside the anonymous classes as the type of the class is `Object` and the `Object` class doesn't have these fields.
While it would be legal to refer these fields inside the anonymous class itself such as :

```
Object a = new Object(){

    Object b = new Object(){

        String c = "Hi!";
        @Override
        public String toString(){
            return c;
        }
    };
};
```

To solve your requirement (access to custom fields) you should not use anonymous classes but your own classes that present the expected structure such as :

```
public class A{
   public B b = new B();
}
public class B{
   public String c = "Hi";
}
```

So you could write (while public instance fields are not at all recommended) :

```
String c = new A().b.c;
```